# get the .class file from ClassLoader in java

Tags: java, classloader, bytecode

I compiled a Class from text

```
public class Foo{
    public Foo(){
    }
}
```

by `org.abstractmeta.toolbox.compilation.compiler.JavaSourceCompile`

and I want to know is there any way to get the compiled bytecode (.class file) from classloader or any any Object

Comment: Google can't find the compiler you're using, and `abstractmeta.com` doesn't seem to be working. Please post a link to the compiler's documentation or Web site.

Comment: hi chrylis that's all https://code.google.com/p/compilation-toolbox/ enjory it :(

Answer (score 0):

you need to write a custom class loader that overloads the findClass method

```
 public Class findClass(String name) {
     byte[] b = ... // get the bytes from wherever they are generated
     return defineClass(name, b, 0, b.length);
 }
```

Comment: thanks mohsin exactly i nedd ...// since my class is not .class file i have a class stored in String and i compile that -runtime- and now i nedd the bytecode is generated by the compilation.toolbox that give me a java.lang.classLoader to load a class

Comment: String clazz = "public class foo{pubic Foo(){}}"

Answer (score 0):

When you're using the [`JavaSourceCompiler`](https://code.google.com/p/compilation-toolbox/source/browse/trunk/src/main/java/org/abstractmeta/toolbox/compilation/compiler/impl/JavaSourceCompilerImpl.java), you have to provide a `CompilationUnit` to both versions of the `compile` method. Call `getOutputClassDirectory()` on this `CompilationUnit` to get the directory that holds all of the compiled `.class` files.

Comment: i try but this is an address in the classpath and there is no .class file

Comment: File m = compilationUnit.getOutputClassDirectory();
        if(m.exists())
            System.out.println("ok");
        else
            System.out.println("ops"); the result is ops

Comment: Did you try that before or after you ran `compile`?

Comment: i try after this line of code  ClassLoader classLoader = javaSourceCompiler.compile(compilationUnit);